# MVC application memory management

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, memory

I would like to get more information regarding memory management in the ASP.NET MVC (5) apps.

For the sake of simplicity, let's say that we have a simple page with angular controller, which only makes a `http.get()` call towards my `api controller` to retrieve 70 000 items of  `IEnumerable<CustomItem>` and afterwards outputs the result to the page (paging is implemented).

When looking at my diagnostic tools (memory profiler) I can see memory rising from 50 MB (starting point) up to 300 MB (once all the data is retrieved).

**Here is the thing I don't understand:**
Why when I open the same page with different browser at the same time (trying to simulate that more users are visiting the page at the same time), the memory consumption for second user does not rise by another 250 MB but it remains the same even though the data has been loaded again?

I was under impression, that `ApiController` is not shared among users but new instance is being created for every user. If I am right and it's really the case, how come that when 70 000 more items arrived the memory consumption didn't change?

Any articles or explanations would be highly appreciated.

**Addition 1:**
My api controller is rerieving data from `SharePoint` and therefore I have to pass all 70 000 records at once to my angular component, which afterwards implements pagination. In other words, my components loads only once all the data (70 000 records) and afterwards displays only portion at the time (otherwise if I used `data-ng-repeat` on 70 000 items my browser used to freeze).

I can surely show my `ApiController` code if necessary, but really its just 3 lines of code which return `IEnumerable<CustomItem>` which only holds three string properties. This is how it looks like:

```
public class SharepointFile
{
    public string FileType { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What database are you using? What does your controller source code look like? What is the average size of a record? It's difficult to say what's going on here. Most of the memory usage could be the app itself and not the data, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Need more info, do you load all the records to memory? if paging is implementted the right way (database side), then you never really have the 70K records on `IEnumerable<CustomItem>`, you just have what you need to show (the current page), and that would not represent a high load for the server.

Comment: From the numbers you are throwing it looks like you are loading all 70k records into memory. For a single paginated query, the memory shouldn't rise so much.

Comment: I do not know what profiler do you use but if not Glimpse (http://getglimpse.com/) try it. Maybe it'll be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The memory rise you see is actual memory used by the process. But .NET may not allocate more memory if memory is free from previously executed request, although all objects will be garbage collected and will be newly allocated, but .NET may not require more memory. Usually processes do not release memory unless are told by OS to do so. They keep on using the memory space.

Unnecessary releasing the memory after each request will require lot of CPU usage and it will create lot of fragmentation in memory at operating system level.

There is always difference between total size of active .NET objects and memory reserved for them.

So for your second request, all 70k objects are not shared, but they are new ones, but process already has empty space to store them, so it will not request more memory from OS.

Comment: is this really true? in this case, how can i tell my proces to give the memory back to the OS ?

Answer (score 0):

You could make your ApiController shared between users, but why would you do that? Those mvc apps are made to be stateless and there's no real need for sharing them between the requests.

What you see in memory consumption is not to be matched with concrete objects in the memory.

You can always profile memory usage by your application to see what is being stored and how much does it allocate. You could try [Ants Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/), or [dotTrace from JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/features/). There's also the good old free [WinDbg](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063(v=vs.85).aspx) in case you can't affort the other ones.

Please also note, that memory management topics may vary depending on how do you host your web app. For instance, in IIS, you will find loads of topics related to memory management of your application pool.

You can use tools like process explorer to compare the working vs virtual size memory.